# Asking about language future and features

Tags: discussion, questions

Is a question of the form **"Is feature X supported / going to be supported in language Y? (and why not)"** appropriate in StackOverflow?

Comment: This seems like it would be a good candidate for FAQ. Should it be tagged with [faq-proposed]?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been asked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on the nature of feature X and language Y. I mean, if it's a really simple, answerable question like:

- Does C++ support pre-processor directives?

You can fall back to the numerous "simple" question threads for your answer of whether SO should be the authoritative source on that.

If it's a question that's more complicated or language-specific, like:

- Will PLINQ eventually include support for WCF Data Services in the final release version of .NET 4.5 or .NET 5.0?
- Or does D have built-in (or library support) for an observer/event pattern?

I think that clearly falls under StackOverflow to answer (as long as its not a duplicate, in which case we can flag it as so!)

If it's more of a theory/conceptual question, like:

- How does the Enumerable pattern work behind the scenes in C#?
- Can you explain the background mechanics of the garbage collector in Java?

It probably belongs on Programmer's

Any of those that end in the **and why** or **and why not**, should also probably go to Programmer's as it's more of a discussion at that point, about the theory of why it was or wasn't included in the language, and no verifiable/working answer can be given.